# HTML table Overflow and search

Tags: c#, html, html-table

I have HTML table that has data coming from a SQL table. I would like 10 row of the table displayed, but it the user click a button beneath the table he can view the next 10 row and so on, also allow to view the previous row as well.

Also if they want to search though all of the data they only come up with them row,

would like a easier search method then the one on the jQuery website if possible,

Comment: What frameword/backend language you are using? PHP, Ruby, Java, ...? There are many solutions. But if your table is not that big or you can paginate with ajax requests I suggest the JQuery plunig Datatables http://www.datatables.net/

Comment: I am using C# asp.net

Comment: there is no code on the page on how to exactly achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 approaches.

1. You can get all your data in array and using one of the jquery table plugins (i recommend http://www.datatables.net/ ) and it handles all the things you wanted. You should only send your array to the table. The problem is if user only wants the first 10 rows, you loaded lotf of data that he does not need but after it loads, it's very quick (it handles with javascript).
2. The second approach is when you get your data from database, you can get only 10 rows (at first , first 10 rows, then second 10 rows and so on) and each time load it to the jquery table (i again recommend http://www.datatables.net/)

Comment: On the site they show an example but i cnat find a tutorial for the example shown

Comment: Goto http://www.datatables.net/usage/ .The only thing you have to do is to create a table like this. I assume you have and array. Foreach value of the array you should only create a <tr> and <td> 's that includes your array. Download it and it has a very useful documentation

Comment: And here may be useful for you: (creating json instead of table-> http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/14242/can-i-use-a-c-codebehind-to-return-my-json/p1)